# FirstOrDefault() i'm getting a ArgumentNullException

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, exception, error-handling, argumentnullexception

I'm getting a ArgumentNullException and i dont know how to fix this.
Ive tried DefaultIfEmpty but it still doesnt work.

Here is the code:

```
if (controller != "Home")
{
    var defaultActionForController = ((List<DefaultActionForControllers>)ViewBag.DefaultActionsForControllers).Where(s => s.Controller == controller).Select(s => s.Action).FirstOrDefault();
    if (controller == "ManagementObjects")
    {
        var controllerName = firstLayerNameSet;
        @:> @Html.ActionLink(firstLayerNameSet, defaultActionForController, controller)
    }
    else if (controller == "MangementCategories")
    {
        var controllerName = secondLayerNameSet;
        @:> @Html.ActionLink(secondLayerNameSet, defaultActionForController, controller)
    }
    else if (controller == "View")
    {
        @:> @Html.ActionLink(Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(controller), "", "")
    }
    else
    {
        @:> @Html.ActionLink(Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(controller), defaultActionForController, controller)
    }
}
```

And here is the error:

```
3005 An unhandled exception has occurred.

ArgumentNullException
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Where[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at ASP._Page_Views_Shared__LoginPartial_cshtml.Execute() in d:\inetpub\wwwroot\TestMap\Views\Shared\_LoginPartial.cshtml:line 30
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
   at ASP._Page_Views_Shared__TopNavbar_cshtml.Execute() in d:\inetpub\wwwroot\TestMap\Views\Shared\_TopNavbar.cshtml:line 13
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
   at ASP._Page_Views_Shared__Layout_cshtml.Execute() in d:\inetpub\wwwroot\TestMap\Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml:line 73
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.<>c__DisplayClass40_0.<RenderPageCore>b__0(TextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult result)
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.RenderSurrounding(String partialViewName, Action`1 body)
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<BeginInvokeAction>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<>c.<BeginExecuteCore>b__152_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c.<BeginProcessRequest>b__20_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.InvokeEndHandler(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult ar)
```

Here is the code of my DefauftActionForControllers:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Heijligers.Mas.Web.Models
{
    public class DefaultActionForControllers
    {
        public string Controller { get; set; }

        public string Action { get; set; }
    }
}
```

i changed the code to this, it didn't work tho:

```
var defaultActionForController = ((List<DefaultActionForControllers>)ViewContext.Controller.ViewBag.DefaultActionForControllers).FirstOrDefault(s => s.Controller == controller).Action;
```

it still gave me a ArgumentNullException.
When i went and debug, it said var defaultActionForController = null
And in ViewBag.DefaultActionsForControllers count 12

idk if that information helps in any way, but i thought of just posting it u never know

Comment: I doubt it's FirstOrDefault, but rather Where that's throwing. My guess is your ViewBag.DefaultActionsForControllers is null

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please post the entire exception stack, not just the error so we can understand what and where it's breaking and help you.

Answer (score 1):

The error stack shows you what the issue is:

```
ArgumentNullException
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Where[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at ASP._Page_Views_Shared__LoginPartial_cshtml.Execute() in 
   d:\inetpub\wwwroot\TestMap\Views\Shared\_LoginPartial.cshtml:line 30
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
```

`Where` is an extension method. As such, it operates on a source and the error is telling you the `source` parameter is `null`.

Check the code that populates `ViewBag.DefaultActionsForControllers`. You need to set the value on the controller's action prior to rendering the view.

Lastly, your method call can be simplified as `FirstOrDefault` allows a predicate as well:

```
var defaultActionForController = ((List<DefaultActionForControllers>)ViewBag.DefaultActionsForControllers).FirstOrDefault(s => s.Controller == controller).Action;
```

Comment: hi!, i changed the method and it still gave me the error. Also, i posted my DefaultActionForControllers class. Maybe you can find the problem there?

Comment: @Daniel  You are not correctly setting the value of `ViewBag.DefaultActionsForControllers` in your controller or you have a cAsE sEnSiTiViTy issue since you are dealing with dynamic properties.

Comment: @Daniel Please post your controller's code. The code for the action in question that is executing when this partial view is loaded.